# Word generating conflicts on GIT

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I'm using dropbox to hold my git repo, and among other things, I have Word documents there.

Strangely, when I try to push a Word document that no one else has pushed (and I know by a fact), it says it's a non linear merge and requires me to pull and manually merge before I can push.

Afaik, that should happen only when someone had pushed the same file I'm trying to update to avoid loosing someone's code, right?
what am I missing?

thanks,

Comment: What a `git --graph --pretty=format:'%h %d %s (%cr) <%an>' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches -- myDocWord` returns? Do you see where the remote/HEAD is compared to your current local HEAD?

Comment: I reckon the git command was ``log``. Well I executed it (``git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h %d %s (%cr) <%an>' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --branches -- mydoc.doc``) and it returned a couple of empty lines. Well, exactly this push didn't asked my to merge anything (I think I had done it this morning), but I will execute this command for each push I do and let you know if anything shows up.

Comment: Which version of Word - i.e. what file format are you using?, and Have you set your attributes/config to say it is "binary" rather than plain text.

Comment: Word 2011, the forma is the old ``.doc``, and no there aren't flags to treat is as binary, but git is doing it so anyways. I thought the problem was rather related to Dropbox and binary files actually. thought could be something related to the file metadata changing differently cos of Dropbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which files were or weren't edited. As long as there are some commits upstream which you don't have downstream git will ask you to perform a pull first. When you pull a merge will happen and if there are no conflicts during that then you can push.

Comment: ... so in essence this problem has nothing to do with Word ;-)

Comment: Hm.. really? It doesn't make that much of sense for me. I mean.. What's the point of doing a merge in something that doesn't requires it? I thought the problem was rather related to Dropbox and binary files actually. thought could be something related to the file metadata changing differently cos of Dropbox..

Comment: A merge is an operation that creates a commit with two parent commits somehow combining the changes made from the last common point for those two commits. If there are no conflicts (for example if different files were changed) then the merge will be automatic. However it's still a merge. If conflicts exist you need to resolve them as part of the merge.

Comment: well, you see.. that's exactly my point. There were no changes in the document in question which would have to be manually merged. please mind "_a Word document that no one else has pushed (and I know it by a fact)_", why on earth I'd have to manually resolve that merge?

Comment: You don't have to manually resolve the merge. You just have to pull before pushing. By default git will only allow you to push if your branch is up-to-date.

Comment: That's the whole question... It is requiring a manual merge... man, have you read the question?

Comment: So I would guess someone made some changes to the file by accident. Have you checked the differences between the two versions? Do they make sense? You can also view recent commits affecting a given path and their diffs with `git log -p [path]` (you would have to checkout origin/master first).